# SAM CLI - Please make sure your database server is running at `localhost`:`5432`

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sam-cli

I am using SAM CLI to start up a local API in WSL like so:

```
sam local start-api --profile my-aws-profile --skip-pull-image -p 4000 -t template.yaml -n local.env.json
```

I am also running a Postgres docker container (also in WSL) which I can connect to fine fro my terminal using the following connection string:

```
postgresql://postgres:mysecretpassword@localhost:5432/postgres?schema=SCHEMA
```

**The issue:**

When I try and connect to the Postgres DB from a lambda function in the SAM local API, I get the following error:

> Please make sure your database server is running at
> `localhost`:`5432`

It seems that the container that runs the SAM API can not access the same network. After researching the solutions for this, I found a few posts mentioning to do the following:

1. Start the SAM local API usig the `--docker-network` flag set to host
2. Update your connection string host to be `host.docker.internal`

I therefore updated my startup command to this:

```
sam local start-api --profile my-aws-profile --skip-pull-image --docker-network host -p 4000 -t template.yaml -n local.env.json
```

and my DB connection string to this:

```
postgresql://postgres:mysecretpassword@host.docker.internal:5432/postgres?schema=SCHEMA
```

But when I do so the connection to the DB just hangs for about 15-20 seconds and then my lambda times out...

Could anyone help me understand why it is still not working? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here you specify 5432 for the port:

```
postgresql://postgres:mysecretpassword@host.docker.internal:***5432***/postgres?schema=SCHEMA
```

While you start your server at 4000

```
sam local start-api --profile my-aws-profile --skip-pull-image --docker-network host ***-p 4000*** -t template.yaml -n local.env.json
```